How do I insert specific attribute values into a products variations in Woocommerce?
I am making a plugin in Woocommerce that imports a json file and creates product variations on the product page. Everything works except defining a single attribute value for the individual product variation. The code can define a variable product's attributes with all its attribute values but the code can not define specific attribute values for the individual product variation. The code $variation->set_attributes($variation_attributes); seems to have no effect. Instead each product variation has all the attribute values defined by the variable product. What is correct syntax for defining a specific attribute value for a product variation?

<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce JSON Product Importer
 * Description: Imports WooCommerce products with variations from a JSON file.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Joe
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wcppi_register_menu');

function wcppi_register_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Product JSON Importer', 
        'Product Importer', 
        'manage_options', 
        'wcppi-importer', 
        'wcppi_importer_page', 
        'dashicons-upload', 
        20
    );
}



function wcppi_importer_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>WooCommerce Product Importer</h1>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="product_json" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="import_submit" value="Import Products">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['import_submit'])) {
        wcppi_handle_import();
    }
}

function wcppi_handle_import() {


    if (isset($_FILES['product_json'])) {
        $json_file = $_FILES['product_json']['tmp_name'];

      
        $json_data = file_get_contents($json_file);
        $products = json_decode($json_data, true);

      
        if (!$products) {
            echo '<p>Error: Invalid JSON format.</p>';
            return;
        }


  

    $array = [
    'pa_color'     => array('Blue', 'Red', 'Green'),
    'pa_size' => array('S', 'M','L'),
    ];

    foreach($array as $attribute_slug => $terms){
        if (!taxonomy_exists($attribute_slug)) {
            $attribute_id[$attribute_slug] = wc_create_attribute(array(
                'name'         => ucfirst(str_replace('pa_', '', $attribute_slug)),
                'slug'         => $attribute_slug, // Attribute slug
                'type'         => 'select',        // Type (dropdown)
                'order_by'     => 'menu_order',    // Order by menu order
                'has_archives' => false,
            ));

            // Register the taxonomy for the attribute
            register_taxonomy($attribute_slug, 'product', array(
                'label' => ucfirst(str_replace('pa_', '', $attribute_slug)),
                'public' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'show_ui' => false,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => false,
            ));
        } 
    }

   
   
    foreach ($array as $attribute_slug => $terms) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if (!term_exists($term, $attribute_slug)) {
                wp_insert_term($term, $attribute_slug);
            }
        }
       
    }
    
           
    


        
    
        foreach ($products as $product_data) {
            wcppi_import_product($product_data);
        }

        echo '<p>Products imported successfully!</p>';
    }
}

function wcppi_import_product($data) {
   
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable();
    $product->set_name($data['name']);
    $product->set_description($data['description']);
    $product->set_sku($data['sku']);
    $product->set_status('publish');
    $product->save();
    
    $product_id = $product->get_id();






    $attributes = array(); // Initializing
    $position   = $attr_id = 0; // Initializing
    
  
    foreach ($data['attributes'] as $taxonomy => $terms ) {
        $attr_id++;
      
        $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute(); 
        $attribute->set_id($attr_id);
        $attribute->set_name("pa_" . lcfirst($taxonomy));
        $attribute->set_position($position);
        $attribute->set_visible(1);
        $attribute->set_variation(1);
        $attributes["pa_" . lcfirst($taxonomy)] = $attribute;
        $position++;
    }
    $product->set_attributes($attributes);
    $product_id = $product->save(); // Save product that returns the product ID
    
  
    foreach ($data['attributes'] as $taxonomy => $terms ) {
        
        wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $terms, "pa_" . lcfirst($taxonomy), true );
    }

 
    foreach ($data['variations'] as $variation_data) {
        wcppi_import_variation($product_id, $variation_data);
    }
}


function wcppi_import_variation($product_id, $data) {
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
    $variation->set_parent_id($product_id);
    $variation->set_regular_price($data['price']);
    $variation->set_sku($data['sku']);
 
    
    $variation_attributes = [];
    foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute_name => $attribute_value) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_' . lcfirst($attribute_name);
        $variation_attributes[$taxonomy] = $attribute_value;
        
    }

    $variation->set_attributes($variation_attributes); 
    $product_id = $variation->save(); 



    foreach ($data['attributes'] as $taxonomy => $terms ) {
       
        wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $terms, "pa_" . lcfirst($taxonomy), true );
    }

    
} 


Here is the json file I am importing:

[
  {
    "name": "T-shirt",
    "sku": "TSHIRT001",
    "description": "A stylish t-shirt",
    "attributes": {
      "Color": ["Red", "Blue", "Green"],
      "Size": ["S", "M", "L"]
    },
    "variations": [
      {
        "sku": "TSHIRT001-RED-S",
        "price": "19.99",
        "attributes": {
          "Color": "Red",
          "Size": "S"
        }
      },
      {
        "sku": "TSHIRT001-RED-M",
        "price": "19.99",
        "attributes": {
          "Color": "Red",
          "Size": "M"
        }
      },
      {
        "sku": "TSHIRT001-BLUE-S",
        "price": "19.99",
        "attributes": {
          "Color": "Blue",
          "Size": "S"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Hoodie",
    "sku": "HOODIE001",
    "description": "A warm hoodie",
    "attributes": {
      "Color": ["Black", "White"],
      "Size": ["M", "L", "XL"]
    },
    "variations": [
      {
        "sku": "HOODIE001-BLACK-M",
        "price": "29.99",
        "attributes": {
          "Color": "Black",
          "Size": "M"
        }
      },
      {
        "sku": "HOODIE001-BLACK-L",
        "price": "29.99",
        "attributes": {
          "Color": "Black",
          "Size": "L"
        }
      },
      {
        "sku": "HOODIE001-WHITE-XL",
        "price": "29.99",
        "attributes": {
          "Color": "White",
          "Size": "XL"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
] 

`


I found a solution. For variation attributes taxonomy is paired with slug (slug for for Blue is blue)

$variation_attributes = [];
    foreach ($data['attributes'] as $attribute_name => $attribute_value) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_' . lcfirst($attribute_name);
        $variation_attributes[$taxonomy] = sanitize_to_slug($attribute_value);
        
    
    }



function sanitize_to_slug($text) {
        
        $text = strtolower($text);
        
        
        $text = str_replace(
            ['å', 'ä', 'ö', 'Å', 'Ä', 'Ö'],
            ['a', 'a', 'o', 'a', 'a', 'o'],
            $text
        );
        
       
        $text = str_replace(' ', '-', $text);
        
       
        $text = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-]/', '', $text);
        
        return $text;
    }


